# My meteor app can't upload from Mongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am relatively a beginner in Meteor.

I can't upload any data from Mongo after I changed my meteor structure. I also added iron:router in order to be able link to other pages.

Here is my repository: https://github.com/hnandarusdy/timesheet

or here is my tasks.html:

---

```
<template name="tasks">    
    {{#each tasks}}
        {{text}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

---

Here is my tasks.js:

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");

Template.tasks.helpers({
  tasks: function(){
    return Tasks.find({});
  }
});
```

I don't have any error in my console. So, I really don't know what the problem is.

Any advice / help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a server folder! None of your code will execute on the server, so the collection won't exist on the server.

Create a `server` folder and add a file to it (say `server/main.js`), with at least the following:

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");
```

That's assuming you still have the `auto-publish` and `insecure` packages loaded.

Comment: Thanks Christian. Yes it is true that I forgot to attach Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");
 in my server side.

Answer (score 0):

Create another folder called 'both' and create a 'collections' folder inside there. Then create separate js files for each collection inside the 'collections' folder.